# Clients connected to dd-wrt AP's cannot be discovered from primary router

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point

I have two dd-wrt devices, one acting as a switch (connected by EoP), and one as an AP (connected by CAT5e). Clients connected to the AP can view the whole network, but clients connected to the router only see clients also connected to it (except the two dd-wrt devices).

*They are on the same subnet and all clients have internet. Oddly enough, right after I reboot the router I can see the whole network, but after a few minutes, it is gone.*
**How can I view the whole network from the router?**
Routing Table while connected to router (192.168.1.1)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

Routing Table while connected to AP (192.168.1.2)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

*(They are identical) I used:*

> # route -n

Comment: Have you turned DHCP off in the DD-WRT's?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes, it is set to DHCP forwarder with address 192.168.1.1 (the router). I just scanned my network and it appears to work (for now). I'll scan again later to be sure. In any case, would you think this would be resolved if I switched to another firmware such as Openwrt? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just checked again and whilst connected to the router I cannot see the whole network except its wireless clients.

Comment: It is not a matter of DD-WRT vs OpenWRT: it should work in any case, full stop. Do all clients belong to the 192.168.1.0/24 network? Can you post the routing table of one of the pcs unable to see the whole network? The AP should be connected to the router as follows: one cable from one of the LAN-side ports of the router to the WAN side of the AP; is this what you did?  While for the switch: all cables on the LAN-side, none on the WAN side.

Comment: I use my phone to scan the network, nonetheless, depending on which AP it is connected to makes them view either the whole, or a part of the network. The clients are in fact on the same subnet; but, I did not connect LAN to WAN on the AP (numerous articles suggest I should not do this anyway). What I find strange is that I can see the switch's clients from the AP, but not from the router, even though it has to go through the router to get there.

Comment: This is exactly what you'd expect if the connection was LAN-to-WAN. If the connection is LAN-to-LAN, this should not happen. DHCP should be completely off in the AP.

Comment: I have a LAN-to-LAN connection via CAT5e from the router to the AP, and the AP is set to forward DHCP from the router (192.168.1.1).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Since I can access the switch from the AP, would this be a misconfiguration in the router or the AP, because I am not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: @Ruben No special DHCP configuration should be necessary. The AP should forward DHCP as it forwards all broadcast traffic. The AP requires no special configuration -- it's just doing what APs do. (I'd suggest configuring the AP for a LAN IP address not inside the router's DHCP range but inside its LAN subnet.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, I have assigned the AP outside the router's DHCP range (and inside the subnet), and after that did not work I tried to do a DHCP reservation for it, which did not change anything. (It is back to 192.168.1.2 again). However, what I really don't understand now is why the AP's clients can see the switch and its clients; but, the router's clients cannot see the switch's nor the AP's clients.

Comment: It's probably the same reason computers on a typical home LAN can see the Internet and the Internet cannot see the computers on a typical home LAN. By default, most home devices do not allow devices on the WAN side to initiate connections to devices on the LAN side. Are you 100% *sure* you have all the used ports bridged together on the AP? (And the WAN disabled or unconfigured.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Are you saying all ports should be bridged together on the AP? (I take it that with bridged you mean converge), because all devices (the switch and AP) converge to the router, but there is no direct link with the AP and the switch. If you don't mean that, the only port used on the AP is the CAT5e cable connected to the router.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I have added the routing tables; however, they are identical. If you want the router and AP's routing tables just let me know.

Comment: Please try connecting a cable on the LAN side of the router to the WAN side of the AP. Despite what articles say, this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Alright I will try this; but, does that mean that I have to do any specific WAN configuration then? Or will it simply 'work'?

Comment: Provided you leave DHCP off, it should just work. There is nothing else to do.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to insert a second router (even though acting only as AP) behind a first router is to connect a cable from a LAN port on the main router to the WAN port on the AP, while leaving DHCP/dnsmasq and what not disabled.

I understand you have often seen the opposite advice (LAN port to LAN port connection) suggested online, but I believe this is incorrect. I have at work and at home several examples  of this configuration, also made with DD-WRT routers (and without them).

Comment: I have plugged it into the WAN port (also does not act as LAN port) but I still cannot view the whole network from the main router. The status page on the AP shows that its LAN IP is 192.168.1.2, but it does not have a WAN IP, so I am not entirely sure how this should work. Also, I don't understand how this will make the switch discoverable from the router (192.168.1.1).

Comment: After I tried this the internet stopped working on the AP, and the network was still (mostly) undiscoverable from the router =/

Comment: @Ruben Sorry to hear that. I have exactly this configuration at home, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Do you think it is a bug? If not do you have WAN disabled on your AP (and it doesn't act as a LAN port)? AND can you see your whole network too? (Thanks for all the help you have given so far)

Comment: I have noticed that (after a complete network reset) I can access the whole network from any device connected to the router. It is just that the moment it connects to the AP and then back to the router again that it stops working. I really do hope that you find the time to reply because I am out of luck. Also, unplugging the AP will thus make everything work too (but this is not ideal).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the switch as an AP too, and disabling the router's 2.4GHz wireless (while keeping the 5.0GHz enabled. I can fully discover my network from every AP now (including the 5.0GHz from the router).